# Python: Can not multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str':: Separating characters from number from input data

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have an input string, each element has a number and character which I want to access each element number and character separately as the following:

```
1s-2r,3d*3 # this is the line in the input file: # this stars means repeated three time
```

So I want to make an array includes only numbers as:

```
number_only=[1,2,3,3,3] # numpy 
s=[s,r,d,d,d] # another array string characters only
```

But I got the following erros "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'".. I know that this should be a intger but I do not know how to do that, attached is the trial code

```
import numpy as np
with open('dataa.dat', 'r') as f:
     input_data = f.readlines()
     input_data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in input_data]
x   =          input_data[0].split('-')
y =          []

for elt in x:
    if "*" in elt:
        n, mult        = elt.split("*")
        y        = y + [(n)] * (mult)
    else:
        y+=[ii for ii in elt.split(',')]
number_only        =          np.array(y)
#s
```

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a string into an `int`?

Comment: @ScottHunter
Thank you for your concern, actually, I am interested in repeat values based number following the star then separate values,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do this is with regex:

```
import re

string = "1s-2r,3d*3"
numbers = re.findall(r"[0-9]", string)
letters = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]", string)
```

Then to convert numbers from str to int:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
```

Edit:

This should do it

```
def parse_string_to_numbers_letters(string):
    string_parts = re.split(r",|-", str(test))
    aggregated_string = ""
    for string in string_parts:
        if re.search("\*", string):
            to_be_multipled = string.split("*")[0]
            multiplier = string.split("*")[1]
            string = to_be_multipled * int(multiplier)
        aggregated_string +=string
    numbers = re.findall(r"[0-9]", aggregated_string)
    letters = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]", aggregated_string)
    return numbers, letters
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, if I do that, I will not able to include star to repeat values for both numbers and string

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question, does 1s-2r,3d*3 evaluate to " 1s-2r,3d1s-2r,3d1s-2r,3d" ?

Comment: Thank you so much again, 
It means/should be as 1s-2r,3d,3d,3d"
and final answer should be for array of numbers only =[1 2 3 3 3]
string=[s r d d d]

Comment: No problem - is the format the same for every line? Try posting the first 10 lines so we can see what's going on and to check the format is relatively stable.

Comment: not sure if I understand what you said or not, but the letters or numbers might be changed but the star is always the same to repeat

Comment: is there always the comma to separate the values that are to be repeated and those that aren't?

e.g: 
1s-2r,3d*3
1s-3s,5e*3
2e-4a,7f*3
etc.

Comment: I wish, i could do something generic, 
but it will be the same format except for letters, and numbers (will change)

Comment: yes, comma and dash always exist

Comment: Hi again, 
Example of the input would be:
1s,2e*3-2q*2,1u
Should be=[1 2 2 2 2 2 1]
and string array=[s e e e q q u]

Comment: ah sorry I didn't realise there were multiple "*"

Comment: No worries,
* to repeat value based on the number after it for example: 3r*2  means=3r 3r 3r so will be [3 3 3], [r r r] 

Sorry if I did not explain what i want clearly, I hope we could find a way 

Thanks,

Comment: I think it's solved now (edited).

Comment: it seems works perfectly even if the number element are more than one, I will check more cases and accept your answer, 

thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This returns numbers from a string:

```
only_digits = ''.join(i for i in string if i.isdigit())
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern, 
However, how could I include repeat ::
how to make this 1s-2r,3d*3    as
1s-2r,3d,3d,3d 
Then 
[1,2,3,3,3]
and [s,r,d,d,d]
Thank you again !!

Comment: No problem, let me know if it's working!

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
import re

def split_string(pat):
    numbers = []
    letters = []

    for s in re.split(r"[,-]", pat):
        count = 1
        if len(s) > 2:
            assert s[2] == '*'
            count = int(s[3:])
        numbers += [int(s[0])] * (count)
        letters += [s[1]] * (count)

    return numbers, letters

def main():
    # The two examples from the question and the comments
    numbers, letters = split_string("1s-2r,3d*3")
    assert numbers == [1,2,3,3,3]
    assert letters == ['s','r','d','d','d']

    numbers, letters = split_string("1s,2e*3-2q*2,1u")
    assert numbers == [1,2,2,2,2,2,1]
    assert letters == ['s', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'q', 'q', 'u']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the meaning of the part of if__name__=='__main__'

Comment: it seems works perfectly, however, if the number is 11 or 20 or two elements, it returns to the following error "in split_string
    assert s[2] == '*'
AssertionError"
So Is there a way to handle that ??

Comment: For the __main__: please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: The questions did only speak about one digit numbers. Do you expect any (integer) number as a first element?